# What makes Slovakia's prosecutor general "pro-Russian"?

Tags: judiciary, slovakia

[According](https://apnews.com/article/slovakia-election-fico-ukraine-russia-democracy-smer-e9e04e59361d927918ff9e8e6e830694) to AP:

> Fico himself faced criminal charges last year for creating a criminal group and misuse of power, but Slovakia’s pro-Russian prosecutor general stepped in and threw out the indictment.

What makes Slovakia’s prosecutor general "pro-Russian"?

Comment: It seems to be talking about Maroš Žilinka.

Comment: The question should really include the name of the subject it talks about.

Comment: Questions are supposed to show research effort. Have you even tried googling?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this would be a rather big part of it:

> At the beginning of 2022, Maroš Žilinka surprised everybody once again, when he published a big red status on Facebook, in which he attacked the cooperation agreement with the USA. [...]
>
> The post says (in translation): The Office of the General Prosecutor of the Slovak Republic submitted 35 key comments to the proposal of defense cooperation agreement between the government of the Slovak republic and the government of the United States of America, because of which we refuse the proposal of the agreement as a whole.

And his apparently frequent trips to Russia, according to the same [piece](https://vsquare.org/mysterious-ways-of-the-slovak-prosecutor-general/), some of which are detailed on the [SK Wikipedia](https://sk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maro%C5%A1_%C5%BDilinka#Prorusk%C3%A9_narat%C3%ADvy) as e.g. him having accepted an invitation "by the Prosecutor General of the Russian Federation, Igor Krasnov, who is on the EU sanctions lists" for the Navalny poisoning issue.